# Prevent Observable from retrying when server is down

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In the piece of code bellow I use `httpClient` to get the list of users from an endpoint,
in a perfect world the app sends one http request and gets the list of users,
but when the server returns a `4xx` or `5xx` error, the app retries after 10 ms and keeps sending thousands of http requests to the server.

```
this.http.get<User[]>(SERVER_API_URL + '/api/not_found')
    .subscribe(
        value => console.log('subscribe.next'),
        err => console.log('subscribe.error'),
        () => console.log('subscribe.done')
    );
```

How can I stop the app from retrying.

I tryed to convert the `Observable` to a `Promise` but I got the same result.

- "@angular/core": "6.0.0"
- "@angular/http": "6.0.5"
- "rxjs": "6.2.1"

Comment: That's not what Observables do so the problem is going to be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: you re right I had a bug in one of my HttpInterceptors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is retry method which automatically re-subscribes to a failed Observable a specified number of times. Re-subscribing to the result of an HttpClient method call has the effect of reissuing the HTTP request.

```
this.http.get<User[]>(SERVER_API_URL + '/api/not_found')
        .pipe(
          retry(0), // retry a failed request up to 0 times
          catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
        ).subscribe(...);
    }
```

reference : https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

You can also unsubscribe.

```
    const sub = this.http.get<User[]>(SERVER_API_URL + '/api/not_found')
        .subscribe(
            value => {
                console.log('subscribe.next')
                sub.unsubscribe();
            },
            err => {
                console.log('subscribe.error');
                sub.unsubscribe();
            },
            () => console.log('subscribe.done')
        );
```